# Supercomputer via LAN

Tags: lan, cluster, parallel-processing

If I decide to parallel two computers via direct LAN connection would LAN (100 Mbits/s) bus bandwidth be enough for CPUs to communicate without performance loss? Or do I have to use some other bus (maybe USB)? Thanks.

**Update**

I want to run resource dependant applications on low power computer. The main idea is to split executed code into code portions which will be sent over machines in cluster and executed by them. There are pipelines which can not be parallelized but there are also an out-of-order execution and threads which are very likely to run parallel.

Comment: What do you expect the computers to do? What data do you need to exchange?

Comment: If you are doing it OK, it'll be Gigabit LAN. You are too broad, but it's probable that your answer be yes.

Comment: @slhck running some heavyweight applications on low power CPU (parallel execution i guess).

Comment: We really need more detail before we can give you a definite answer. Something like compiling a linux kernel can be made faster with more machines...

Comment: It depends on your definition of "performance loss."  There will be some amount of latency (delay) introduced by transmitting data between the computers, but the effect of this on your application's performance is highly dependent on your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I think the CPUs won't communicate with each other. It's your program which defines what shall be sent to the other PC(s).

Then, it of course varies depending on the task you're trying to accomplish. Can the individual PCs perform work on data which is not needed to be accessed by anyone else or not?

Another important question is: How much data is it? Examples:

- cracking keys, you only need to transfer the key (512 bit), which takes milliseconds to transfer and it will need some minutes to process. That's ok.
- If you're rendering a 3D scene, you'll need to transfer all pictures and object information. That's maybe 200 MB per scene (transfer in 15 seconds) and need ~ 1 hour to process. Also fine.
- if you need 1 GB of data (transfers in 76 seconds) but the calculation can be done in 30 seconds, it's not worth it.

Rule of thumb for the data size: if it takes longer to transfer the data then computing on it, it's probably not worth. If you have multiple PCs, divide the bandwidth by the number of clients.

Comment: Rendering a 3D scene is not too bad either. You send the save file, the networked computer renders its timeslice, then it transmits the result back to be stitched together has a movie file. Almost all 3D rendering software available today has [plugins](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/files/Network_rendering_Network_render_with_Maya_software_.htm) for [distributed](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/ps/dl/item?siteID=123112&id=5581724&linkID=9241177) [rendering](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Render/Performance/Renderfarm).

Comment: Yes, I'm using network renders with Blender. It's ok because the ratio between transferring the scene and rendering it is ok. If there was more data (e.g. 500 MB) but less processing time (e.g. 1 minute), it would not be worth doing it with a 100 MBit/s network. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Networked supercomputers are only good in scenarios where you might want to execute multiple independent tasks. Also if you need a supercomputer in the first place you will surely need enormous bandwidth for data transfer so a 100MB LAN will not be sufficient.

Here is a simple wikiHow to build one http://www.wikihow.com/Build-a-Supercomputer

But let me warn you it is not as easy as it sounds. You will also need to modify and recompile the programs you want to run to make them modular among a million other things.